# Restrict the user from typing anywhere else other than in the text box in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have designed a letterhead with a background, a header, a footer and a big text box as the 
box into which to type the letter.

How can I restrict the user from typing anywhere else other than in the text box?

Answer (score 2):

1) Convert it to a Word template:

[Save a Word document as a template](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/word-help/save-a-word-document-as-a-template-HA101868862.aspx)

1. Click the File tab, and then click New.
2. Under Available templates, click New from existing.
3. Click a template or a document that is similar to the one that you want to create, and then click Create New.
4. Make the changes you want to the margin settings, page size and orientation, styles, and other formats.
5. Click the File tab, and then click Save As.
6. In the Save As dialog box, do one of the following:

   On a computer that is running Windows 7, scroll to the top of the folder list, and under Microsoft Word click Templates.
   On a computer that is running Windows Vista, under Favorite Links, click Templates.
   On a computer that is running Windows XP, under Save in, click Trusted Templates.
7. Give the new template a file name, select Word Template in the Save as type list, and then click Save.
8. Close the template.

2) Protect it from changes:

[Protect a Word template from unauthorized changes](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/support/protect-a-word-template-from-unauthorized-changes-HP001173086.aspx)

1. Open the file.
2. Click the Microsoft Office Button Button image, and then click Save As.
3. Click Tools, and then click General Options.
4. Do one or all of the following:

   Create a password to open
   Create a password to modify
5. Click OK.
6. When prompted, retype your passwords to confirm them, and then click OK.
7. In the Save As dialog box, click Save.
8. If prompted, click Yes to replace the existing document.

Additional info related to making a fillable form in Word:

- [Create forms that users complete or print in Word](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/word-help/create-forms-that-users-complete-or-print-in-word-HA010030746.aspx)
- [Video: Create forms that users complete or print in Word](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/word-help/video-create-forms-that-users-complete-or-print-in-word-HA010335135.aspx)

Comment: hello techie- thanks for the the replt which answers quite a few concerns-- how ever what i want to do is allow typing only into the text box and not elsewhere.could you help?

Comment: OK so convert it to a protected template with the textbox in it.  Can they still type in the textbox? Can they type elsewhere? Also, I added a couple more links to the bottom of my answer that may help with your task.

Comment: thanks techie-- I am tired now and am going to bed- will try both links tomorrow